# mySQL query joining association table matching this AND this OR this

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I need a little help. Not sure why I can't make sense of this one.

I have a table for songs, genre and an association between the two.

```
SONGS
song_id
song_name
active (0,1)

GENRE
genre_id
genre_name (rock,jazz,classical,newage,opera)

ASSOC
song_id
genre_id
```

I can do a simple search like this...

```
SELECT s.song_name, s.song_id
FROM (songs s)
LEFT JOIN assoc a ON s.song_id = a.song_id
WHERE s.active = 1
AND a.genre_id = 1
```

And a multi search like this.

```
SELECT s.song_name, s.song_id
FROM (songs s)
LEFT JOIN assoc a ON s.song_id = a.song_id
WHERE s.active = 1
AND (a.genre_id = 1 
   OR a.genre_id = 2)
```

BUT, what if I want to get 1 and 2 OR 3? This does not work.

```
SELECT s.song_name, s.song_id
FROM (songs s)
LEFT JOIN assoc a ON s.song_id = a.song_id
WHERE s.active = 1
AND a.genre_id = 1
AND (a.genre_id = 2 
   OR a.genre_id = 3)
```

Thanks in advance for help. I have a feeling I am just looking at this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a self-join:

```sql
SELECT s.song_name, s.song_id
FROM   songs AS s
  JOIN assoc AS a1 ON a1.song_id = s.song_id AND a1.genre_id = 1
  JOIN assoc AS a2 ON a2.song_id = s.song_id AND a2.genre_id IN (2,3)
WHERE  s.active = 1
```

Comment: @jcho360: Quite right, my bad.  I have introduced a self-join as you suggest.

Comment: Yikes, I really need a new JOIN for each genre_id or group of genre_ids I want to match. Is there a better way to do this? I used to have the IDs in the song record and used FIND_IN_SET(), but I figured this would be faster.

Comment: @Thom: You can implement "any *n* of genres a,b,c,d" (including where *n* = 4, which would give only songs in all four genres; or where *n* = 1 which obviously gives all songs in any genre) by selecting results in any of those genres then grouping by song and filtering for only those groups having at least *n* constituent records.  But to implement more advanced logic does unfortunately require a more advanced query; you could achieve the same with a subquery in a `WHERE EXISTS ...` clause, but it's unlikely to be any faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   SELECT s.song_name, s.song_id
    FROM (songs s)
    LEFT JOIN assoc a ON s.song_id = a.song_id
    WHERE s.active = 1
    AND (a.genre_id = 1
    OR a.genre_id = 2 
       OR a.genre_id = 3)
```

your where clause was wrong because

```
AND a.genre_id = 1 AND (a.genre_id = 2 OR a.genre_id = 3)
```

that's mean in one row  you have two options

```
a.genre_id=1 and a.genre_id=1 or
a.genre_id=1 and a.genre_id=3
```

and you only have a genre_id per rows, so you can't not have 2 values in the same rows

Comment: "*what if I want to get 1 and 2 OR 3?*".  This answer doesn't deliver this.

Comment: @eggyal the result will always be 0 at least he make a self join, did you see my explanation why that will happen?

Comment: eggyal is right. I am looking for results that have 1, and 2 OR 3.  Also might need 1, and 4, and 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.song_name, s.song_id
FROM (songs s)
LEFT JOIN assoc a ON s.song_id = a.song_id
WHERE s.active = 1
AND (a.genre_id = 1
  AND a.genre_id = 2) 
OR a.genre_id = 3
```

I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: that would get 1 or 2 or 3. I am looking for 1 and 2 or 3.

Comment: ok, edited it thusly, I was assuming you could only have one kind of .genre_id